# Why is only the last item showing when I want to print a list from a file in python?

Tags: python, list, file

Just a warning I am as beginner as it gets with python so I might ask for clarification with answers if it's beyond what I've learned in class.

My text file is titled 'data.txt' and looks like this (the file ends at 80):

```
90

100

80
```

My code looks like this:

```
data = open('data.txt', 'r')

    for line in data:
        newLine = line.strip('\n')
        dataList = newLine.split('\n')

    #This closes the file
    data.close()
    
    print('The numbers are ', dataList)

    countNumbers = len(dataList)

    print('The count of the numbers is ', countNumbers)
```

When I run the program the output is:

```
The numbers are  ['80']

The count of the numbers is  1
```

So I don't understand why I am not getting back all 3 elements of the list. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the last number is because you are just saving 1 item to the dataList variable in every loop, you are not creating a list. You are overwriting it at every loop.

I am not sure what your text file looks like but it seems like there are spaces between each line, so my data.txt file literally looks like this. It has 5 lines, 3 with something and 2 blank ones in between.

```
90

100

80
```

Okay so here is my code,

```
data = open('data.txt', 'r')
dataList = [] #create empty list

for line in data:
    new = line.strip('\n')
    if new: #check if there is data because when you strip a blank new line, you still get an empty string
        dataList.append(new) #append line to dataList

data.close()
print('The numbers are ', dataList)
countNumbers = len(dataList)
print('The count of the numbers is ', countNumbers)
```

Here is my output,

```
The numbers are  ['90', '100', '80']
The count of the numbers is  3
```

Here is an implementation with split that gives the same result. Not recommended because it's not as efficient since we know that there is only 1 item per line. We just need to get rid of the `\n` (new line character).

```
data = open('data.txt', 'r')
dataList = []

for line in data:
    new = line.split('\n')[0] #select first item in array
    if new:
        dataList.append(new)

print('The numbers are ', dataList)
countNumbers = len(dataList)

print('The count of the numbers is ', countNumbers)
```

Comment: Why didn't you need to use the split function? I thought the split function was needed to turn the string into usable integers

Comment: @whatsanoven because there is only 1 item per line, there is no need.

Comment: @whatsanoven there are many ways to code this, I can do it with split if you want as well, you can also do it with replace, you just need to know what you are dealing with

Comment: @whatsanoven i have updated my answer to use the split method at the end you can take a look

Comment: Ohh okay. Can you also tell me what "if new:" means ? I learned about if statements but I don't understand that it says "if <variable>:". Like, if it exists ?

Comment: basically `if something` means that that block of code will only be executed if `something` has data in it, meaning the variable has something in it. if it is empty then it wont run that code for that loop, so my code is saying, check if the variable new has any data in it, if it is empty, then dont append anything to dataList, but if it's not empty, then append data, the reason i had to do that is because there are blank lines in between, if i removed that block, the output would have been `The numbers are  ['80', '', '100', '', '90']` and the length would have been 5.

Comment: @anarchy: Using `split` here just because the OP *thinks* they want it is bad; if the OP really needs it, sure, include it as a comment on the same line, but do something idiomatic as the real code (hopefully they learn the correct solution). `new = line.rstrip()` or `new = line.rstrip('\n')` is idiomatic (quickly scanning backwards without checking values over the whole length of the string). Scanning the whole string and splitting to make a `list` just to grab the single value from it? Eww.

Comment: im just trying to explain that theres many ways to do this thats all

Comment: @whatsanoven if you look at the other answers they are all correct too

Comment: @anarchy: Thank you so much, this has been really helpful. I wasn't aware if the split function was necessary or not for this because we had spent a lot of time learning delimiters before we were assigned the project. I appreciate that you put two different ways though

Comment: When I try to do "sumNumbers = sum(dataList)" it says "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'". Are they not turned into integers ?
Edit: never mind I changed the line to dataList.append(int(newLine)) and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
data = open('data.txt', 'r')

dataList = []

for line in data:
    if line != "\n":
        dataList.append(line.replace("\n",""))
   

#This closes the file
data.close()

print('The numbers are ', dataList[:])

countNumbers = len(dataList[:])

print('The count of the numbers is ', countNumbers)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Does "if line != "\n":" mean that if the line is not is not \n ?

Comment: If the line is different from "\n" add it to the list

Answer (score 1):

Use the `read` method to turn the entire file into an array of strings, then iterate through the file:

```
data = open('data.txt', 'r')

dataList = []
for number in data.read().split("\n"):
    if number != '':
        dataList.append(int(number))

#This closes the file
data.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can** do it just in *one line*, using the `splitlines` method like this:

```
data = open('data.txt', 'r')
dataList = data.read().splitlines() # Put the file line by line  in a List
dataList = list(filter(None, dataList)) # Remove all empty list elements

data.close()


print('The numbers are ', dataList)
countNumbers = len(dataList)
print('The count of the numbers is ', countNumbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could give a try to my approach buddy.I certainly hope this helps, pal!

```py
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines_lst = [line.strip() for line in f.read().splitlines()]
    [lines_lst.remove(el) for el in lines_lst if el ==""]
        
    print('The numbers are ', lines_lst)
    print('The count of the numbers is ',  len(lines_lst))
```